# Proof that Markov Chains converges to the stationary distribution

Tags: markov-chains, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, markov-process

Let $P$ is a transition matrix of a Markov Chain, which is irreducible, aperiodic and lets assume $\pi$ is its stationary distribution: $\pi = \pi P$. Does anyone knows the proof for the following fact (given $\pi_0$ is valid probability distribution):
$$\forall \pi_0 \lim_{n \to \infty}\pi_0 P^n = \pi$$
I know the proof when if $P=Q\Sigma Q^{-1}$is the eigenvector decomposition and $Q^{-1} = Q^{T}$. But how do I prove it in the general case, when the eigenvectors are not orthogonal to each other?

Comment: You also need the chain to be aperiodic to get convergence.

Comment: True that, I'll add it to the requirements.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to rpove this when eigenvectors are not orthonormal

Comment: Yes. Look up Perron-Frobenius theory, in particular, convergence to the Perron projection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An elegant probabilistic proof uses the notion of *coupling*. See Theorem 8.6 of Billingsley's *Probability & Measure*. For another proof see Chapter 4 of *Markov Chains and Mixing Times* here http://pages.uoregon.edu/dlevin/MARKOV/