# Requirements for a Markov chain to converge to its stationary distribution.

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process, stationary-processes

I have seen in two places, different requirements for a Markov chain to converge to its stationary/invariant distribution:

1. Irreducibility and aperiodicity. As mentioned [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/588251/762889)
2. Irreducibility and recurrence.

---

Is it true that under irreducibility and recurrence then the stationary distribution is also its limiting distribution?

And how does recurrence relate to aperiodicity, is one requirement stronger than the other?

Comment: Just consider a 2-state system with states $S=\{1,2\}$ and $P_{12}=P_{21}=1$. This is clearly irreducible and recurrent.  It has a solution $\pi=(1/2,1/2)$ to the stationary equation $\pi = \pi P$. However, it is periodic and if we start in state 1 (at time $0$) then we will always be in state 1 on even slots and state 2 on odd slots, so the limiting probability does not exist due to oscillation.  On the other hand, the time average fraction of time being in each state does converge to $(1/2,1/2)$.

Comment: Thank you for this example. My confusion comes from the fact that different Ergodic theorems in the context of MCMC algorithms, stated different assumptions. Some do not mention the assumption of aperiodicity, or they replace it with recurrence or with Harris recurrence.

Comment: Without aperoidicity, you can still get convergence of the time average with probability 1. Its just that you cannot get convergence of the probabilities themselves. The time average statements are usually obtained by *renewal theory.*

Answer (score 1):

For an example, see my comment on the discrete time Markov chain (DTMC) with $S=\{1,2\}$ and $P_{12}=P_{21}=1$, which is irreducible, recurrent, and periodic and has a solution $\pi = (1/2,1/2)$ to $\pi = \pi P$.

Here is my favorite steady state theorem: For a finite or countably infinite state space $S$, define a "probability vector" as a nonnegative vector $(\pi_i)_{i\in S}$ that satisfies $\sum_{i \in S} \pi_i=1$.

**Theorem:** Suppose $\{X_t\}_{t=0}^{\infty}$ is a DTMC with finite or countably infinite state space $S$ and transition probability matrix $P=(P_{ij})$.  Suppose the DTMC is irreducible and there is a probability vector $(\pi_i)_{i\in S}$ that satisfies
$$ \pi_j = \sum_{i\in S} \pi_i P_{ij} \quad \forall j \in S \quad \mbox{(stationary equations)}$$
Then

a) We must have $\pi_i>0$ for all $i \in S$.

b) Regardless of the initial condition $X_0\in S$, we have for all $i \in S$:
$$ \lim_{T\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=0}^{T}1_{\{X_t=i\}} = \pi_i \quad \mbox{(with prob 1)}$$
where $1_{\{X_t=i\}}$ is an indicator that is $1$ if $X_t=i$ and $0$ else.

c) Additionally, if the DTMC is aperiodic then for any $x_0\in S$:
$$ \lim_{t\rightarrow\infty} P[X_t=i|X_0=x_0] =  \pi_i \quad \forall i \in S$$

---

Other useful facts for general (possibly periodic) DTMCs with finite or countably infinite state space $S$ and (homogeneous) transition probability matrix $P=(P_{ij})$:

- If the DTMC is *irreducible* then there is **at most one** probability vector solution to the stationary equations.
- If the DTMC has a *finite state space* then there is **at least one** probability vector solution to the stationary equations.

Comment: Ok great thanks, this makes sense that even without aperiodicity the empirical distribution converges to the stationary distribution. So we can use an aperiodic MCMC to estimate moments of the invariant dist. I just need to understand a bit more about recurrence and when it is important.